# Symfony 5 / EasyAdmin 3 / VichUploader for a multi files upload at once, in one field

Tags: symfony, symfony5, easyadmin, vichuploaderbundle, easyadmin3

- Bundle version : vich/uploader-bundle 1.17.0 (checked with composer
  show -i)
- Symfony version : 5.2.5
- PHP version : 8.0.2

I had a perfectly working multi files upload. Upload one file at a time with one "browse" button.
It's basically a Package entity that can have Many images.

I am trying to modify it to upload all files at once through only one "browse" window. Select multiple files with Ctrl / shift.

I tried tons of modifications by gathering informations on stackoverflow / youtube / github ...
I revert back most of them and here is the current situation.

I have the browse button, I can select multiple files at once and when I click SAVE I have this error message :

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Image", "App\Entity\Package" given at property path "images".

It comes from `public function addImage(Image $image): self` in `Package.php`
If I add a `dump($image);` in this function and select two images in my Browse popup, hit save, I can see that both images are added.

Now if I remove the Entity check :

```
public function addImage($image): self
```

There is a third dump($image); called with a Package entity provided.

Here is my code.

https://gist.github.com/cedricgeffroy/b977ecbea8c7e603eac97d623a936cf0

I will post below the code for future googlers if I find the solution, but It seems that a gist was the best option for now considering the number of files.

So am I missing something or is my setup missing some logic?
Thank you anyway for reading and any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but maybe it will be useful for someone. Check your `PackageType.php`. I think, in `configureOptions` you should change
`data_class` from `Package::class` to `Image::class`